# Elegantly check for null before method call

Tags: javascript

How do I elegantly check for null before calling a method on an object? This is how I do it right now:

```
var title = document.querySelector('title');
title = title ? title.text : '';
```

Null Object pattern would be nice in this case but I don't own the `document.querySelector` code.

Comment: `var title = document.querySelector('title') || {text:''};`

Comment: @Shmiddty that's wrong. The OP wanted to get either title text or blank. Your code returns either the title object or an object with a property `text` with a blank string.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer That's a replacement for the first line, not the second. Then title.text works as the OP expects.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer what Fizzy said. OP could do this: ...................................................................... `var title = (document.querySelector('title') || {text:''}).text;`

Comment: @Shmiddty I got it. I just preserved the comment for future clarification.

Comment: @Shmiddty You should re-post your comment as a proper answer

Comment: It might be worth pointing out, for other readers if not for you Sven, that the answer depends on the rest of your system. It's likely that @Shmiddty's answer is what you are looking for. But if a missing title is an error that should be dealt with, then the solution is to write *more* code than you have done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var title = document.querySelector('title') || {text:''};
```

then just use `title.text` in-line.

Alternatively, you could use this one-liner:

```
var title = (document.querySelector('title') || {text:''}).text;
```